# Dimmer for Nth-Light Narrow LED Flexible Strip Light

Tags: led

I wish to dim a Nth-Light Narrow LED Flexible Strip Light (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3683), will the LED Strip Lights PWM Dimming Controller For LED Lights or Ribbon, 12 Volt 8/10 Amp, 3301 ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003L4KKF2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003L4KKF2)) will be suitable?

Comment: yes, that will work. make sure your power supply is capable as well.

Answer (score 0):

One strip specs are :
12V DC @ 65mA    = 800 milliwatts
LEDs/ ft.: ~1,200  ( lots of tiny Leds )  *that seem to be arranged in 96 clusters of 24P4S*
Luminous Efficacy: ~30 lm/Watt  ( not great )
CRI: ~73 CRI  typical
Color Temp: ~5000 K  neutral

So the 8A dimmer is overkill for one strip but shud work.

Any 12 supply can handle this low current but the voltage affects the current used so it is rated for 12.0V

The web specs could be wrong and it recommends a 1A supply, so watch out for voltage tolerance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain what you mean in "Any 12 supply can handle this low current but the voltage affects the current used so it is rated for 12.0V"

Comment: 65mA is pretty low current but they arrange 4 clusters 3V each to get 12V with the internal resistance and tighter Voltage supply tolerance to limit the current, unlike Stripleds which use repeating 3LED strings + R to limit current  3x3.x +If*R= 12V with a wider tolerance to supply voltage so many can be used on cars from 12 to 14.2V, but not these.